# Add an additional custom class to select2-container

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-select2

I need to add an additional class to select2-container container to to add ability for a phonetic keyboard for the live search field.

Like

```
$("#e2").select2-search__field({
customClass: "atk",
});
```

So that results container will be formed as

```
<input class="atk select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox">
```

Can anyone provide me a solution to this. Tried using dropdownCssClass but its atk to everywhere. I just need it added to a specific one only

Comment: can you build a small example we can work with

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the [documentation](https://select2.org/configuration/options-api) of `search2` and found the `containerCssClass` property. Now I am not familiar with `search2` so I can't say for sure, but you might try this.

```
$("#e2").select2-search__field({
    containerCssClass: "atk",
});
```

And if it doesn't work, manually add the class with standard jQuery.

```
$(".select2-search__field").addClass("atk");
```